# php regular expression to filter data

Tags: php, regex

i am just getting stuck with php regular expression to filter data. I want to detect 'Results 1 - 20 of 60' using regular expression and then delete the data from `$content`

```
$content="We have Results 1 - 20 of 60 some blah blah blah";
$content = preg_replace("/regular-expression/", " ", $content);
```

Here expected output is: `We have some blah blah blah`
Any Idea?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to solve the wrong problem. What are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly, here is a solution

```
$content="We have Results 1 - 20 of 60 some blah blah blah";
$content = preg_replace("/(Results)(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)(-)(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)(of)(\\s+)(\\d+)/", " ", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
 $content = preg_replace("/\s*results\s+\d+\s+-\s+\d+\s+of\s+\d+\s*/i", " ", $content);
```

to remove `Results 1 - 20 of 60`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via

```
<?php
    $str="We have Results 1 - 20 of 60 some blah blah blah";
    echo preg_replace("/(Results)(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)(-)(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)(of)(\\s+)(\\d+)/", " ", $str);
?>
```

**Output**

```
We have some blah blah blah
```